# How to iterate a list of words to find word with some pattern?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, text

I want to merge tagged city names of two words, and print. How can I move the iterator forward and do that with loop(s)?

```
sentence = "There are many cities. Random text, city name <c.first> New </c.first> <c.last> York </c.last> and text continues."
sentence = sentence.split()

#print(sentence)

for word in sentence:
    if(word == '<c.first>' ):
        print(word)
      # Here I want to be able to find New York, as single element and print. Output 'New York'
```

Comment: Do you want to print all the cities in your sentence? If so, will they all be two words, tagged with `<c.first>` and `<c.last>`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just print out all the words after each tag, then you can do the following, where `tags` is a list of tags.

```
sentence = "There are many cities. Random text, city name <c.first> New </c.first> <c.last> York </c.last> and text continues."
sentence = sentence.split()

found_tag = False

tags = ['<c.first>', '<c.last>']

for word in sentence:
    if(word in tags):
        found_tag = True
    elif found_tag:
        print(word)
        found_tag = False
```

This will print:

```
New
York
```

Comment: That's a very ingenious solution, indeed. Thank you. However, I also want to able to print (or do something) if there are more than one words in any of those tags. Say, <new_tag1> A LONG </new_tag1> <new_tag2> STRANGE CITY NAME </new_tag2>

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Ollie for the idea, that I could find the solution to my problem. I want to count the entire city name as one entity somehow. Not sure if this is an efficient way though. So, I would still welcome suggestion(s).

```
sentence = "There are many cities. Random text, city name <c.first> New City of </c.first> <c.last> York </c.last> and text continues.  <c.first> A LONG </c.first> <c.last> STRANGE CITY NAME </c.last>"
sentence = sentence.split()

found_tag = False

#tags = ['<c.first>', '</c.first>', '<c.last>','</c.last>']

opening_tags = ['<c.first>',  '<c.last>']
closing_tags = ['</c.first>', '</c.last>']

for word in sentence:
    if(word in opening_tags):
        found_tag = True
    elif found_tag and word not in closing_tags:
        print(word, end =' ')
    elif word in closing_tags:
        found_tag = False
```